# I have some questions about `int 13h`

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, boot, bios

I have read that `int 13h` provides functionalities to disks and floppy...
I have written this code:

```
    _start:

    mov cl, 2;sector
    call printSector

    ;write 
    mov ah, 3
    mov al, 1     ;Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0     ;Cylinder number 
    mov cl, 3     ;Starting sector number
    mov dh, 0     ;Head number
    mov dl, 0x80  ;Drive number
    mov bx, tB  ;Address of memory buffer
    int 0x13

    jc errmsglb ; err check

    mov cl, 3;sector
    call printSector

    ;quit
    jmp quit


;;;;;;;;
;functions

printSector:
    mov ah, 2
    mov al, 1     ;Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0     ;Cylinder number 
    mov cl, cl     ;Starting sector number
    mov dh, 0     ;Head number
    mov dl, 0x80  ;Drive number
    mov bx, buf  ;Address of memory buffer
    int 0x13

    jc errmsglb ; err check

    ;print buf
    mov bx, buf
    mov cx, 1
    call print
    ret

print:
    push dx
    mov dx, 0;salva conteudo de dx na stack e move 0 para contar numero de caracters

    printLoop:
    mov ah, 0x0e;print call
    mov al, [bx];addr do conteudo
    cmp dx, cx;comparo dx com cx para saber a len
    je quitPrint
    int 0x10;syscall

    inc bx;para o addr passar para o proxima letra
    inc dx;add a len 
    jmp printLoop
    quitPrint:
    pop dx;volta o valor do dx
    ret


errmsglb:
    mov bx, errmsg
    mov cx, errmsgLen
    call print



;;;;;;;;
;final
quit:



;vars
errmsg: db "error", 0
errmsgLen: equ $ - errmsg
buf: db 0 
tB: db 'B'

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
times 512 db 'A'
times 512 db 0
```

So, I'm trying to read the 2nd sector, as the first is occupied by boot sector, and it works. I read it to *buf* and print it, simple, but then I try to write 3rd sector and it gives NO errors, but then when I read it, it doesn't give the 'B' stored in the variable that I think I write.

Probably I'm not understanding how writing works.

Also I have another question. Supposedly I'm reading from disk, but I'm writing to the sector with `times 512 db 'A'`, and that is in the code, that in my mind is in the memory not in the disk... Does someone can explain me how this all works or get me some good documentation?

Comment: Yes, the `times 512 db 'A'` is in the code, you assemble it and get a binary that **you** write to the disk so that's how it ends up there. You did not show the steps you take, but I assume you do have some process writing to the disk.

Comment: im converting it to bin and running it on qemu, maybe qemu write it in someway??

Comment: When you run `qemu` you attach it as a disk, don't you?

Comment: i dont really know but ill try to run it on virtual box or vmware

Answer (score 2):

> So, im trying to read the 2 sector, as the first is occupied by boot sector, and it works i read it to buf and print it, simple, but then i try to write 3 sector and it gives NO errors, but then when i read it, it doesnt give the B stores in the variable that i think i write.

The code that reads the 2nd sector stores 512 bytes at the *buf* label where, based on what you wrote, you have set aside only 1 byte.

> ```
> buf: db 0 
> tB: db 'B'
> ```

So the 'B' (and the 510 bytes that follow) gets overwritten by the contents of that 2nd sector. Later when you write to the 3rd sector starting at the *tB* label, there's no more 'B' for you to verify after reading that 3rd sector.

The solution is to not use these 'buffers' *buf* and *tB* that reside within the bootsector, they can never accomodate 512 bytes anyway, but rather use the buffers that you've already defined after this bootsector code.

> ```
> times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
> db 0x55, 0xaa
> times 512 db 'A'               <-- 1st buffer is at 0x7E00 (This is your sector 2)
> times 512 db 0                 <-- 2nd buffer is at 0x8000 (This is your sector 3)
> ```

You know that BIOS loaded your 512-byte bootsector (**but not those extra buffers**) in memory at address 7C00h. Inevitably the first extra buffer will reside at 7E00h and the second extra buffer will reside at 8000h. Of course the code only truly needs a single general purpose buffer for its operation. So, rewrite your code using the known address of 0x7E00:

```
    ...

    mov  cl, 2
    call printSector  ; This will print 'AAAA'

    mov  dx, 0x0080
    mov  cx, 0x0003
    mov  bx, 0x7E00  ; Address of memory buffer (general purpose)
    mov  byte [bx], 'B'
    mov  ax, 0x0301  ; BIOS.WriteSector
    int  0x13
    jc   errmsglb

    ; The 3rd sector now contains one character 'B' followed by 511 characters 'A'.

    mov  cl, 3
    call printSector  ; This will print 'BAAA'

    jmp  quit


; IN (cx,si)
print:
    mov  bx, 0x0007   ; DisplayPage=0, GraphicsColor=7 (White)
    mov  al, [si]
    mov  ah, 0x0E     ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  0x10
    inc  si
    dec  cx 
    jnz  print
    ret

; IN (cl)
printSector:
    mov  dx, 0x0080
    mov  ch, 0
    mov  bx, 0x7E00  ; Address of memory buffer (general purpose)
    mov  ax, 0x0201  ; BIOS.ReadSector
    int  0x13
    jc   errmsglb
    mov  si, 0x7E00  ; Address of memory buffer (general purpose)
    mov  cx, 4
    call print
    ret

errmsglb:
    mov  si, errmsg
    mov  cx, errmsgLen
    call print

quit:
    ...

errmsg:    db "error"
errmsgLen: equ $ - errmsg

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
db    0x55, 0xaa
times 512 db 'A'
```

Tip: Don't use BX for the address when using BIOS.Teletype function 0x0E. The byte-sized registers BH and BL, that make up BX, have special meaning when this function runs:

- BH is DisplayPage
- BL is GraphicsColor (for when the screen is a graphical one)

Comment: thx for help, finally i can understand this, i really appreciate ur time

Comment: just a small question...when u print whats in the 3rd sector u will call "mov  bx, 0x7E00"...  will it not replace whats in the 2nd secor?? as it lives in 0x7E00. I tried it where and it doesnt overwrite.. but why? in my head it is writting whats is in the 3rd secotor to 0x7E00 and there lives the 2nd sector

Comment: @Rabyt You have to make a clear distinction between the (hard) **disk** and the **memory**. When you say "... replace whats in the 2nd secor??", the mention 'sector' refers to the disk, and for the disk I assure you that the 2nd sector does not get overwritten by reading/printing the 3rd sector. It's a bit confusing to me that you write "as it lives in 0x7E00". Sure, the 2nd sector was **copied** to the buffer at 0x7E00, but it is only the **copy** that gets overwritten. For the demonstration purpose of reading/writing disk sectors, this was not a problem.

Comment: @Rabyt If you need to keep multiple disk sectors in memory, then you can use more than the one memory buffer that my demo is using. Remember that upon booting the memory is yours. You can use a second memory buffer at 0x8000 and a third at 0x8200. You can even spread these buffers to very different addresses as long as their memory ranges don't overlap, because that would cause havoc on the data contained therein.